# QML: GridView/SwipeView with drag and drop

Tags: qt, qml

I have a list of lets say 20 buttons (this number can change dynamically) in a `listView` which I want to display using a `grid` on a `swipeView` or `gridView`. Only 6 buttons should be visible at once. In addition, it should be possible to exchange the position of buttons via drag and drop (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-draganddrop-example.html). In case `gridView` is the way to go, is it possible to have it behave like `swipeView`, so that the buttons can not be moved to an arbitrary position but lock onto their column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to give [`snapMode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#snapMode-prop) a try.

You have the choice of:

> - `GridView.NoSnap` (default) - the view stops anywhere within the visible area.
> - `GridView.SnapToRow` - the view settles with a row (or column for GridView.FlowTopToBottom flow) aligned with the start of the view.
> - `GridView.SnapOneRow` - the view will settle no more than one row (or column for GridView.FlowTopToBottom flow) away from the first visible row at the time the mouse button is released. This mode is particularly useful for moving one page at a time.

You need to make sure, that the size of the `GridView` really fits your desired amount of delegates, for it will only make sure, that the first element is aligned, not that there is no element paritally protruding the view.